# Left Join in Mysql?

Tags: mysql, left-join

This is my first Table.

[image: table1]

Then the second one is

[image: table2]

Now I am trying to do Left join like this

```
SELECT t1.StackID FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.StackID=t2.StackID
```

Output

[image: output]

I am confused here, Is this the correct output? Is not this supposed to return only the 5 rows which is present in left side table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's correct output. You are doing `LEFT JOIN`, so for every record in LEFT table DBMS will 'concatenate' the corresponding RIGHT table record(-s) (and NULL, if there's no corresponding record for the `JOIN` condition; also remember, that if there are more that 1 corresponding record - *all* will be joined - this issue is why you're getting not only 5 records from 1-st table).

The thing you're trying to achieve should be done by either `DISTINCT` modifier, i.e.

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.StackID FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.StackID=t2.StackID;
```

More about JOIN in SQL you can read [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29).

Answer (score 2):

There is a simple example of left join:-

```
SELECT * FROM a JOIN b LEFT JOIN c ON (c.key=a.key) LEFT JOIN d ON (d.key=a.key) 
WHERE b.key=d.key;
```

Answer (score 1):

These extra repeated values of `StackId` are coming from the `join`, just use `DISTINCT` to get those only 5 values:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.StackID 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.StackID=t2.StackID;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c55c1/1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the expected output.

To get the distinct IDs, use `DISTINCT` -

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.StackID 
FROM t1 
LEFT JOIN t2 
ON t1.StackID=t2.StackID
```

When you left joined your `t2` table with `t1` based on `stackID`, then the database will join every row of `t2` with the every row of `t1` which has the same `stackID` value. Since `1` appears in six rows in the `t2` table as a `stackID` value, all of them are joined with the first row of `t1`. Similar thing is true for all other values.

Answer (score 0):

To give yourself a little more understanding of how a left join works try this:

```
SELECT t1.StackID, t2.StackID FROM t1 LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.StackID=t2.StackID
```

basically a left join returns **all** the rows from the left table plus matching ones from the right.